# Can I make PDF the default for 'print to file'

Tags: configuration, pdf

I am using 10.04 and I use the 'Print to File' feature a lot but it's annoying to have to change the output option to to PDF each time.  Is there a way to make it the default?

[image: 'Print to File' dialog]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install the `cups-pdf` package, add a new printer of the type "Generic CUPS-PDF Printer", and then make that the default printer.

I don't use this myself, so I am not sure if the quality of the PDFs that creates is different (for better or for worse) than what the "save to file" feature provides though.  (Maybe you can comment here on your experiences with it?)

Comment: The quality is comparable but you don't get to specify the file name, it just saves it in '~/PDF'

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I made PDF the default:

Make Print-to-File default to PDF in Firefox.

#### First, open Firefox, then:

1. about:config
2. print.print_to_filename
3. /home/*user*/Desktop/mozilla.pdf

   #### If the above instructions do not work, continue with the following:
4. Print something from an installed printer using Firefox (entry may not show otherwise)
5. about:config
6. Type "print_to_filename"
7. Identify the entry that has the exact name of the printer attached to your computer
   (e.g., print.printer_Canon-xxxx.print_to_filename)
8. Change the Value to: /home/*user*/Desktop/mozilla.pdf

Comment: Useful only for Firefox, but a good tip regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I did some looking around interesting question. There is some discussion on Ubuntu forums.

Here are a couple of link I found useful, they seem to be talking about firefox method of changing it! I hope this helped you. :)

Here is the [blog](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/change-the-default-print-to-file-to-pdf-in-ubuntu-hardy) post on the topic as well as couple of [Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1228123) forum links discussing the [topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043339).

Comment: Please put meaningful text in the links. Especially for accessibility this is terrible.

Comment: I apologize. fixed. :)