# How do I configure the "Print_to_PDF"-printer and where does it print to?

Tags: 10.10, pdf, printing

I have a printer queue called "Print_to_PDF". I don't know why and where from I have it, and also not how I can configure it. If I print using that printer, I cannot find the output file anywhere.

Answer (score 12):

Generally speaking, there is not need to use the PDF printer anymore, because you should have the generic "Print to file" option in every printer dialog. This option allows you to choose PDF or Postscript and also an output directory. If you have an additional PDF printer, this is because you have the `cups-pdf` package installed. If you send something to this printer, it should end up in a special `PDF` directory in your home directory, i.e. in `~/PDF`.

Comment: But how can I **change the destination folder** of the default *Print to file* option?

Answer (score 3):

As Marcel said, the CUPS-PDF "Print to PDF" functionality is no longer needed as "Print to File" gives you the same functionality.  However, if you do have it installed, it will only work if you have a directory named "PDF" in your home directory.  I had to actually create that directory in my home folder to get the "prints".

You can create it by opening a terminal and typing:

```
mkdir PDF
```

It is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Did You try this?

[Can I make PDF the default for 'print to file'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2710/can-i-make-pdf-the-default-for-print-to-file)